# What happens when we pass hashtable inside Collections.synchronizedMap()

Tags: java, spring, collections

Today I have asked a question in my interview.
The question is that Collections.synchronizedMap() is 
used to synchronize the map which are by default not thread safe like hashmap.
His question is but we can pass any kind of map inside this method.
So what is the effect when we pass a hashtable inside this method because hashtable is by default synchronized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior of the map will be the same, but the performance will be affected, because each method will acquire two synchronization locks instead of one.

For example, consider calling the method `size()` on the resulting map. The implementation in the `Collections.SynchronizedMap` class looks like this:

```
public int size() {
    synchronized(mutex) {return m.size();} // first lock
}
```

... where, `m.size()` calls the implementation in `Hashtable`:

```
public synchronized int size() { // second lock
    return count;
}
```

The first lock object is the `mutex` field in `SynchronizedMap`. The second lock is implicit - the `Hashtable` instance itself.

Answer (score 2):

You would have two synchronization levels: one at the level of the synchronized map itself, implemented by a mutex object, and one at the level of the wrapped instance:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // first level synchronization
    synchronized(mutex) {
        // second level synchronization if c is a Hashtable
        return c.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

The additional synchronization is not needed and can lead to lower performance.

Another effect is that you won't be able to use API from `Hashtable` like [`Hashtable#elements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#elements--) since the wrapped collection is now strictly a `Map` instance.

Answer (score 1):

It will get wrapped into a `SynchronizedMap`, from `java.util.Collections`:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> synchronizedMap(Map<K,V> m) {
    return new SynchronizedMap<>(m);
}
```

The `synchronizedMap()` method does not distinguish between the types of `Map`s passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

"His question is but we can pass any kind of map inside this method."

The answer is yes, because the constructor of `SynchronizedMap` accepts every `Map` in it's signature.

"So what is the effect when we pass a hashtable inside this method because hashtable is by default synchronized"

The answer is: We are showing ignorance to the `ConcurrentHashMap` which is most likely the tool to be uses instead of a blocking implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code in the `SynchronizedCollection`. The methods will delegate the call to the underlying collection but adding synchronized block on top of the call something like this

```
public int size() {
 synchronized (mutex) {return c.size();}
}
```

The implementation of the size looks like this in `HashTable` class

```
public synchronized int size() {
    return count;
}
```

So, if you pass in `HashTable` to `SynchronizedCollection`, the thread accessing to `SynchronizedCollection` will have to take the locks at 2 levels once for synchronized block and another for synchronized method. 
If there are other threads using the HashTable object directly, they can block the threads using the `SynchronizedCollection` even when the thread got the lock on `SynchronizedCollection`.

Comment: Copy of Natix's answer?

Comment: I wrote the answer in parallel to him I think, I am not sure why it is ordered below, plus I have given one reason why not to do it.